# Tooltipster doesn't work with dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I've been dealing with this problem for some days but I can't find the solution. I have a function in Javascript that generates HTML after an Ajax call is done and I call this function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list").change(function() {
        reloadInfo($('#list').val());
    });
    reloadInfo($('#list').val());
});
```

And my function is the next:

```
function reloadInfo(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    ...
    code += "<img id='led_" + res.id + "' src='green_led.gif' style='cursor: pointer' class='tooltipstered'>";
    code += "<img id='" + res.id + "' src='mygraph.jpg'>";
    ...
    div.innerHTML = code;
}
```

After that, I've tried to use Tooltipster in order to show 'mygraph.jpg' into a tooltip when I put the mouse over the 'green_led.gif' image and hide it when I move out the mouse cursor. To do so, I've used the next code into my $(document).ready():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list").change(function() {
        reloadInfo($('#list').val());
    });
    reloadInfo($('#list').val());

    $("body").on('mouseover', '.tooltipstered', function(){
        $(this).tooltipster({
            trigger: 'custom'
        }).tooltipster('open').tooltipster('content', 'MYcontent');
    });
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I've read Tooltipster documentation but I don't know what I'm doing wrong when I generate dynamically the HTML code (when I try it with static HTML it works, but I do it a bit different):

#### JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tooltipstered").tooltipster({
            trigger: 'custom',
            arrow: false
        }).on('mouseover', function() {
            $(this).tooltipster('instance').content("foo").open();
        }).on('mouseout', function() {
            $(this).tooltipster('instance').close();
        })
    });
```

#### HTML

```
<body>
    <button id="1" class="tooltipstered" style="float: right">Hover1</button>
    <button id="2" class="tooltipstered">Hover1</button>
</body>
```

The problem is when I generate HTML with JavaScript. First time I put the cursor over the image I don't get any error in the browser console, but the second time I repeat it i get this errors:

- Tooltipster: one or more tooltips are already attached to the element
  below. Ignoring.

> ```
>    <img id=​"led_27269" src=​"green_led.gif" style=​"cursor:​ pointer" class=​"tooltipstered">​
> ```

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

If anybody knows what I'm doing wrong it would be of help. Thank you very much in advanced!!

Comment: Have you read http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#delegation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things :

- You shall destroy the `tooltipster`s and recreate them on HTML content change.
- Calling a `tooltipster` method shall be done via `$(...).tooltipster(methodName, arg1, arg2,...)`. Here you should look at the documentation for correct method name and arguments. So, you should call the creation (without method name) each time as you did in `$("body").on('mouseover' ...`.

For recreation :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tooltipstered").tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom',
        arrow: false
    }).on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).tooltipster('instance').content("foo").open();
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).tooltipster('instance').close();
    })
});
```

shall be moved :

```
function reloadInfo(id) {
    $(".tooltipstered").tooltipster('destroy');

    ... your reloading code

    $(".tooltipstered").tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom',
        arrow: false
    }).on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).tooltipster('instance').content("foo").open();
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).tooltipster('instance').close();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @MasterDjon, I was calling methods in the wrong way.